# Convert data.frame into another one exploding data contained into its column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that contains a recordset of 10 rows from a PostgreSQL query.
the recordset is composed by these elements:

month - year - vector_values

where vector_values represents a vector with values (each instance of vector_values has 4000000 elements).
the data.frame dimension is:

> nrow(mydata_frame) = 10
>
> ncols(mydata_frame) = 3

I'm trying to convert this data.frame into a data.matrix (or data.frame) exploding the third element in order to obtain a matrix with ncols as the number of vector_value elements'

```
new_dataframe <- data.frame(mat_points[,1],mat_points[,2],as.numeric(unlist(mat_points[,3])),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

but it doesn't work: if I check the new_dataframe dimensions I will obtain :

> nrow(new_dataframe) = 4000000
>
> ncols(new_dataframe) = 3

I don't known where I wrong

Comment: How are the values in the third column delimited? You might be able to use the `separate` function from `tidyr` with something like `separate(my_df, var_3, into=paste('v', 1:4000000), sep=',', extra='merge', fill='right', remove=TRUE)` where sep is replaced with whatever your values are separated by.

Comment: thank you for the idea, i tried it but it doesn't work: when I run the script, the followed error appears:  'var' must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list